# No module named 'object_detection' import error

Tags: python, tensorflow, object, object-detection

I know most of you who have worked with tensorflow object detection have come across this problem. I have my tensorflow project running in a different folder but now I did like to use *object detection  functions* stored in *models folder*.

I have changed my working directory in my python scripts to **models / object detection** folder this way:

```
import sys
import os
changed_directory = False

if not changed_directory:
    os.chdir(os.path.join('../models/research/','object_detection/')) 
    changed_directory = True
```

I then append the path in my scripts this way :

```
import sys
sys.path.append("...models\\research\\object_detection\\")
```

This is how my models folder looks like

```
TensorFlow/
NAR_object_detection/
└─ models/
   ├─ community/
   ├─ official/
   ├─ orbit/
   ├─ research/
   └── ...
```

*Object detection folder* in inside the *research models*. Also important to say that my python scripts for object detection are stored in a folder called **NAR_object_detection** inside the **Tensorflow**, so I mean **NAR_object_detection folder** is the same folder with **models folder**.

When I try to import this way I get an error that no module called object detection

```
from object_detection.utils import label_map_util
```

Why is it that the import statement is not finding the object detection folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
pip install tensorflow-object-detection-api
```